# Formatting a compact code block in Confluenc

Tags: formatting, confluence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem

In the above link wiki generates a "compact" inline code block, that is, the block stops at the last letter of the code instead of the whole line.

Is there a way to achieve this effect in confluence wiki?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB, the only way to do this is with **monospace** text, but you don't get the background and border.

On Confluence Cloud, you have no other option.

If you are on Confluence Server, you could add a new user macro:

```
## Macro Name: decorate-inline-code
## Macro Title: Decorate Inline Code
## Macro has a body: N
## Body processing: n/a
## Output: HTML
##
## Developed by: David Simpson
## Date created: 2016-12-08
## Installed by: Your Name

## Simple user macro to decorate inline `<code>hello world</code>` blocks with a border & background color
## This should not decorate any `<pre><code>:(</code></pre> blocks
## @noparams

<style> 
#content code:not([class]) { #* ignores <code> in the code macro *#
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1px 4px;
}
</style>
```

This user macro can be added to the page once.

- It finds all `<code>` blocks on a page and decorates them with a background and border
- It ignores `<code>` in the code macro